# Frozen screen while installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu, screen, freeze

I am reviving an old desktop, trying to put a Ubuntu distro...tried Xubuntu and Lubuntu. And in both this screen appears when I click to install the system.

I actually have Windows XP on that pc, but I wanted to change for one of these distros... How can I solve this?

PCspecs:

```
Motherboard: ASRock Prescott 800
CPU: Celeron 2.8 Ghz
Graphics: NVidia geforce fx 5200 (128 MB)
2 GB ram
```

[image: whyyyyy?!]

Comment: You may need `nomodeset`.

Comment: @MichaelBay What'sthat? I red an article here in askubuntu, but I can't even install the  OS...

Comment: @MichaelBay thanks! I figured out! On the F6 button and select nomodeset. Thanks mate

Comment: That is supposed to be a workaround only. Usually `nomodeset` is used with unsupported graphics (no longer supported in this case) for installing and booting until the Nvidia drivers are installed. Problem: Your card is supported up to version 173 and this version is so ancient it is not compatible with newer kernels. Upgrade the hardware if possible.